# Beginner oop question: modifying a variable and using it in another method

Tags: python, oop

I am writing some unit tests which I have simplified to the following:

```
class BuyTicket(TestCase):

    ipn = {
        "payer_email": "bishan_1233269544_per@gmail.com",
        "quantity": "1",
    }

    def setUp(self):
        self.attendee = create_user(username='attendee', \
                                    email='attendee@foobar.com')
        self.client = Client()

    def test_1(self):
        self.quantity = 100
        self.ipn['quantity'] = self.quantity

    def test_2(self):
        # I would like to use the updated values of ipn['quantity']
        # in this method
```

I know I could do this using **global** but it's generally regarded to be bad form. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you want to do that: 
 I think Unittest creates a new instance of BuyTicket for each test function, and calls setUp before each test.

If one test depends on another like you describe, you should factor out the dependency into separate code or call from the setup() function.  If you *really* need to do what you say, then declare ipn at the module level.

Comment: Well, the params in ipn are actually quite a lot more and I didn't want to clutter my code. Looks like theres no other way?

Comment: As @macek noted, each unit test is supposed to stand alone. There can be a setup part and a teardown part, but you are not even supposed to count on your unit tests being run in a certain order. (This is helpful because later you can run `python -m unittest mymodule.BuyTicket.test_1` to only test one feature ) 
So if you are counting on some setup to ipn for both test cases, do something like:
`
def setupIPN(self):
  ...
def test_1(self):
  self.setupIPN()

def test_2(self):
  self.setupIPN()
  test_more_things()
`
But by convention your IPN setup code should run twice.

Answer (score 0):

This breaks the convention of unit testing.

Each test method needs to start from the same starting point.